# Grab unsaved document from response received after server validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using (have to) `Rails 3.2.12` and ruby `1.9.3` with mongoid as orm

Maybe my question doesn't make sense but let me ask

I want to know the ID or any other attribute of the unsaved document which is not being validated.

Like in the following screenshot I want to grab the ID of the second document whose one attribute is invalid. This page was rendered because server validation didn't go through.

[image]

Comment: Do you have some controller and view code to support your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not entirely clear from your question what is causing validation to fail, the text "can't be blank" is usually coming from `ActiveModel::Errors`.

Whenever validation is failed on the model and the page is re-rendered, it passes a hash that looks like this (example for a class `Item` that fails `:create` because it's missing a name):

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fe63fcff710 
  @base=#<Item id: nil, name: nil, user_id: 15, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, 
  @messages={:name=>["can't be blank"]},  
  @details={:name=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

Inside that hash you will have lots of useful information (including the "can't be blank error" that is showing in your example). You can grab those errors in a number of different ways, but often you do it with an instance variable in the controller. For example:

```
class WhateverController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)

    if @thing.save
      ...do success stuff...
    else
      flash[:error] = @thing.errors.full_messages
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Call Byebug (or similiar) at the top of the else statement and then you can have a look in the console what is in `@thing.errors`

If the record is not being created, you won't have an ID in the hash (because it hasn't been saved), but if it's an update action then it should appear in the errors hash.